# Asp.net 5 Entity Framework 7.0.0-rc1-final explicit transaction error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework-core

I am trying to use an explicit transaction in an ASP.NET project. When debugging, as soon as the line with the using( var transaction = ... is reached
the following exception is thrown:

"No service for type 'Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.IRelationalConnection' has been registered"

I have included my dependencies below. Am I missing something in my Startup file?

```
 using (ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            try
            {
                using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
                {
                   //do some work
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc) { }

        }
```

My dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
"EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
"EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final" }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because ApplicationDbContext has not been configured to use a specific provider. There are several ways to configure your DbContext to point to your database, as explained in [Configuring a DbContext](http://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext.html) on EF Core's official docs.

For example,

```
public class ApplicationDbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
         options.UseSqlite("Filename=./test.db");
    }
}
```

Or if you want to use dependency injection,

```
// in Startup.cs
services.AddEntityFramework()
  .AddSqlite()
  .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
      options.UseSqlite("Filename=./test.db"));

// in a constructor argument
public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext context)
...

// in code

using(var context = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>())
....
```